# Change a bitmap image in listView after listView was created

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an AsyncTask that gets favicon base on a URL.
I am creating a listView, that has a favicon and a URL. at the moment even though I have the AsyncTask my UI waits for the asyncTask to finish before it shows the next activity.

I would like my activity to start with a default image that is stored in drawable, and that the AsyncTask will replace the images after it got each favicon.

Any ideas how to do it?

my AsyncTask:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Bitmap> {
    final AccountListModel model = new AccountListModel(daoSession);

protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... urls) {
    URL urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        mIcon11 = model.getBitmapFromURL(urldisplay);
        //try to get image
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    faviconBitmap=result;
}}
```

the way I am currently creating my list view

```
for (Site site : model.getSites()) {
    try {
    String url = site.getDomain()
    faviconBitmap= new DownloadImageTask().execute(new URL("http", "www."+ url.trim(),"/favicon.ico")).get();
    if (faviconBitmap != null) {
       Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(faviconBitmap,32, 32, true);
       accountsAndUsersList.add(newAccountListScreen(scaled,site.getName());

                    }
                }

    else {
            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.favicon);
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 32, 32, true);
        accountsAndUsersList.add(new AccountListScreen(scaled,site.getName());
                    }           
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
         sitesToSortArray = new AccountListScreen[accountsAndUsersList
                .size()];
        accountsAndUsersList.toArray(sitesToSortArray);
        AccountListAdapter adapter = new AccountListAdapter(this,
                R.layout.account_list_row, sitesToSortArray);
        listViewAccountList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activityAccountList);
        listViewAccountList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

please let me know if you would like to see my adapter as well.
Thank you!

Comment: give a look at this article http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Comment: I have seen this one, unfortunately i did not understood how to modify my code accordingly

Comment: How are you creating the image view in each list item? If you are using a layout, then try to set the drawable in the xml and it will get replaced once the task is completed. Otherwise, if you are creating the image view in your java code, set the drawable resource id and once again it should get replaced once your task finishes.

Comment: The method in the article StarsSky provided is not efficient starting from Android 2.3 you should use the android lrucache method http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html I also recommend that you read all parts of Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently not only the caching part.

Comment: @praneetloke- could you give me an example? I can add the relavent xml/adapter code if necessary